# rsync does not append some files

Tags: rsync, rclone

I have mounted dropbox using rclone to `/home/user/Dropbox`. I'm using rsync to upload the files to dropbox. I have done so around 400GB just using this method.

[image: dropbox capacity]

Today however it uploaded some files and stopped with the summary of the tranfer (no errors) like it has completed tranferring all the files.

However, when I check the source directories, there are some files left. Since I'm using `--append` and `--remove-source-files` flags, there shouldn't be any files left.

I tried to copy one of them using file manager and it shows that the file already exists at the targed and prompt to replace.

Following is the command I used.

```
❯ rsync \
-var \
--append-verify \
--remove-source-files \
/media/s1n7ax/92802CA0802C8CB3/Digikam/ \
/home/s1n7ax/Dropbox/Camera\ Album/
sending incremental file list
./
2022-07-23 Wewathenna/
2022-07-23 Wewathenna/Raw/
2022-10-16 Dolukanda/
2022-10-16 Dolukanda/Edited/
2022-10-16 Dolukanda/Raw/
2022-10-16 Dolukanda/Udul's Photos/
2022-11-06 Nuwara Eliya/
2022-11-06 Nuwara Eliya/Raw/
2022-11-20 Peradeniya Botanical Garden/
2022-11-20 Peradeniya Botanical Garden/Raw/
2022-12-13 Pinnawala/
2022-12-13 Pinnawala/Raw/
2023-01-21 Riverston/
2023-01-21 Riverston/Anura's Photos/
2023-03-25 Gatemore/
2023-03-25 Gatemore/Raw/
2023-04-08 Kanawiddagala/
2023-04-08 Kanawiddagala/Raw/

sent 36,726 bytes  received 153 bytes  1,715.30 bytes/sec
total size is 121,892,420,904  speedup is 3,305,198.65
```

I tried to copy a directory that only contains files too.

```
❯ rsync \
-var \
--append-verify \
--remove-source-files \
/media/s1n7ax/92802CA0802C8CB3/Digikam/2022-07-23\ Wewathenna/Raw/ \
/home/s1n7ax/Dropbox/Camera\ Album/2022-07-23\ Wewathenna/Raw/
sending incremental file list
./

sent 505 bytes  received 19 bytes  1,048.00 bytes/sec
total size is 1,316,281,020  speedup is 2,511,986.68
```

Details of one file

Source:

```
ls -l 1Y3A8976.CR3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 s1n7ax s1n7ax 50107478 Jul 23  2022 1Y3A8976.CR3
```

Target:

```
ls -l 1Y3A8976.CR3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s1n7ax s1n7ax 50107478 Jun 29 20:56 1Y3A8976.CR3
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything in the manual about it, but it appears `--append`/`--append-verify` ignore files that are newer on the destination (which is true for your example).

Basically, it seems like append implies `--update`.

It doesn't explain how you got into this situation, but it does explain why your current invocation isn't cleaning it up.